# Android SQLite no such table exception

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm having an exception while trying to insert a new record into the table as follow:

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
Log.d("INSERT: ", "Inserting...");
db.addAirport(new Airport("Ben Gurion","LLBG","TLV","Israel","Tel-Aviv","IL"));
```

DatabaseHandler.java:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "airportsDB";

    private static final String TABLE_AIRPORTS = "airports";

    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "airportname";
    private static final String KEY_ICAO = "icao";
    private static final String KEY_IATA = "iata";
    private static final String KEY_COUNTRY = "country";
    private static final String KEY_CITY = "city";
    private static final String KEY_COUNTRYCODE = "countrycode";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String CREATE_AIRPORTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_AIRPORTS+" ("
                    +KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+KEY_NAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_ICAO+
                    " TEXT, "+KEY_IATA+" TEXT, "+KEY_COUNTRY+" TEXT, "+KEY_CITY+
                    " TEXT, "+KEY_COUNTRYCODE+" TEXT"+")";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_AIRPORTS_TABLE);
        }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_AIRPORTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addAirport(Airport airport){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, airport.getName());
        values.put(KEY_ICAO, airport.getICAO());
        values.put(KEY_IATA, airport.getIATA());
        values.put(KEY_COUNTRY, airport.getCountry());
        values.put(KEY_CITY, airport.getCity());
        values.put(KEY_COUNTRYCODE,airport.getCountryCode());

        db.insert(TABLE_AIRPORTS,null,values);
        db.close();
    }


}
```

Airport.java

```
public class Airport {

    int id;
    String name, icao, iata, country, city, countryCode;

    public Airport() {

    }

    public Airport(int id,String name,String icao,String iata, String country, String city, String countryCode)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.icao = icao;
        this.iata = iata;
        this.country = country;
        this.city = city;
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }

    public Airport(String name,String icao,String iata, String country, String city, String countryCode)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.icao = icao;
        this.iata = iata;
        this.country = country;
        this.city = city;
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getICAO()
    {
        return this.icao;
    }

    public String getIATA()
    {
        return this.iata;
    }

    public String getCountry()
    {
        return this.country;
    }

    public String getCity()
    {
        return this.city;
    }

    public String getCountryCode()
    {
        return this.countryCode;
    }

}
```

Logcat error:

```
01-28 11:39:24.150    1877-1877/com.example.avis.flightstats E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: airports
01-28 11:39:24.150    1877-1877/com.example.avis.flightstats E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting iata=TLV countrycode=IL airportname=Ben Gurion icao=LLBG city=Tel-Aviv country=Israel
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: airports (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO airports(iata,countrycode,airportname,icao,city,country) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
            at com.example.avis.flightstats.DatabaseHandler.addAirport(DatabaseHandler.java:62)
            at com.example.avis.flightstats.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:24)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 11:39:24.210    1877-1877/com.example.avis.flightstats D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8d8ca30, tid 1877
01-28 11:39:24.270    1877-1877/com.example.avis.flightstats W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-28 11:39:24.270    1877-1877/com.example.avis.flightstats D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

I checked several times the table creation query but it seems perfectly fine.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Even though I'm getting an exception it seems like it did insert the new record:
http://i.imgur.com/NTwZN02.jpg
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that `getWritableDatabase()` has been called, or else the `onCreate()` code will not be run. Simply creating the helper does not call `onCreate()`, so the table hasn't been created when you go to insert into it.

Edit: From the [API documents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase%28%29) for `getWritableDatabase()`:

> Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and writing. The first time this is called, the database will be opened and `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase)`, `onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int)` and/or `onOpen(SQLiteDatabase`) will be called.

Comment: I specified at the addAirport function:
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Is it possible that you already have a verison of the database on the phone you're testing this on? Can you uninstall and reinstall the app, and try again?

Comment: What do you mean by uninstall the app ?
I run the app using the emulator.

Comment: This error is also typically caused when you change the columns on a table without changing the version number. This leads on `onUpgrade()` never being called, and you get "no such table" when you try to insert data onto it. To confirm, use ADB to see if the table exists and if it contains all of the columns that you are using in `addAirport()`. EDIT: Alternatively, try increasing the verison number and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I tried to increase the database version to 2 and 3 but no luck.

Comment: Do you see the table when you check the database over ADB? What does the table schema look like?

Comment: OK.
I pulled off the airports database file and it looks like it did insert the record perfectly.
See here:
http://i.imgur.com/NTwZN02.jpg

Comment: Do you have any idea sir ?